# Where is the detailed Gantt chart in Microsoft Project 2016?

Tags: microsoft-project

I am new to Microsoft Project and following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIrshh-0s3I&t=3s) tutorial on youtube. The tutorial is based on Microsoft Project 2013. On Minute 9:34 he whips out a detailed Gantt chart which is not found in the same menu location on my Microsoft Project 2016 version. Does anyone know where I can find the detailed Gantt on the 2016 version?

Answer (score 0):

Oops. I just found it. It is in View (Gantt Chart) > More Views> Detail Gantt > Apply.